# How to get the marker or glyph mapped to a column of a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn

I want to map a markers to a particular column called species which is not a quantitative column and do not feature in the scatter plot matrix.I want to do something like this which is not supported in pairplot by seaborn?How can I do it in python?

```
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap, factor_mark
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

Species=['A','B','C']
Markers=['hex', 'circle_x', 'triangle']
#df=Panda dataframe
sns.pairplot(df, hue="mammals",diag_kind = 'hist',
         marker=factor_mark('species', Markers, Species))
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, seaborn doesn't allow you to vary marker with a variable. I think the easiest way is to plot with hue as Species, and assign the markers.

This is built on the premise that for each species, it would correspond to one category in mammals. Below I use a simplified example with 3 species, A being "Y" in species and B and C being "N":

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1':np.random.uniform(0,1,20),
                   'var2':np.random.uniform(0,1,20),
                   'var3':np.random.uniform(0,1,20),
                   'Species':np.random.choice(Species,20)})

df['mammals'] = ['Y' if i == 'A' else 'N' for i in df['Species']]
```

We can create a mapping

```
species2mammals = df.groupby('Species')['mammals'].agg('unique').to_dict()
species2mammals

{'A': array(['Y'], dtype=object),
 'B': array(['N'], dtype=object),
 'C': array(['N'], dtype=object)}
```

We specify the markers for each species and for each mammal category:

```
Species = ['A','B','C']
Markers=["H", "v", "^"]
Mammals_col = {'Y':'#f3c623','N':'#127681'}
```

Then we define the colors for each species based on their mammal:

```
Cols = [Mammals_col[i[0]] for i in species2mammals.values()]
```

And plot it:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(df, hue="Species",palette=Cols,hue_kws=dict(marker=Markers))
g = g.map_diag(plt.hist, histtype="step", linewidth=3)
g = g.map_offdiag(plt.scatter)
g = g.add_legend()
```

[image]